# How to retrieve the parameters inside a method which is in form of string?

Tags: c#, string

I need to find the parameters in a method which is a `string`

```
"MyMethod1(int a ,int b){Console.WriteLine("the sum is"); return(a+b);}"
```

**Required output**

```
"int a ,int b"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
(?<=\().*?(?=\))
```

**Explanation**

- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\()`

  - Assert that the Regex below matches
  - `\(` matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
- `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)

  - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- Positive Lookahead `(?=\))`

  - Assert that the Regex below matches
  - `\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)

**Example**

```
string str1 = @"MyMethod1(int a ,int b) blah blah (asd)";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\().*?(?=\))");
Match match = regex.Match(str1);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ITaqAU)

Answer (score 0):

**Without Regex**

```
string str1 = @"MyMethod1(int a ,int b) blah blah (asd)";
int start = str1.IndexOf("(") + 1;
int length = str1.IndexOf(")") - start;
Console.WriteLine(str1.Substring(start, length));
```

[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/XUQ77375)